# need guidance on using pre-trained weights in segmentation_models API

Tags: tensorflow, keras, image-segmentation, pre-trained-model, semantic-segmentation

I want to use a pre-trained Unet model using [segmentation_models](https://segmentation-models.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html) API for the [Cityscapes](https://www.cityscapes-dataset.com/) dataset, but I need the pre-trained weights for the same. Where can I find the pre-trained weights for a Unet model trained on the Cityscapes dataset?

Please guide me on this!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UNet is absent from the [benchmark](https://www.cityscapes-dataset.com/benchmarks/#scene-labeling-task) so i assume it is not adapted for this dataset (too slow and not enough performant probably). However, I advise you to start with [DeepLabv3+](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.02611) from Google which is not so complicated and more adapted for this dataset.

You can use this [repository](https://github.com/bonlime/keras-deeplab-v3-plus) where it is implemented, well documented and useable with pretrained weights from cityscape dataset (and also [PascalVOC](http://host.robots.ox.ac.uk/pascal/VOC/) dataset).